# Multi-Language iPhone Apps with Different Embedded Video, Audio content

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I have read that the best practice for multi lingual apps is to use localization, which totally makes sense. I raise this thought about multi apps, one app per language, because an app I worked on has separate video and audio content embedded right in the app so there is no buffer time or streaming.

The client has more video and audio content for Mandarin and Spanish. Does this constitute a new app for every language?

Anyone have any experience with apple on this? The English version is already approved in the store.